# Linq to Objects - Performance

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Ao procurar conteúdo sobre boas práticas ao fazer utilizar LINQ me deparei com a seguinte situação de filtro:

```
// Filtros
int idBairro = 8626;
```

1º jeito:

```
IQueryable<TesteConsulta> queryCidade = (from c in db.ERPCEPCidade
                                         select new TesteConsulta
                                         {
                                             idCidade = c.idCidade
                                         });

if (idBairro != 0)
{
    var queryBairro = (from b in db.ERPCEPBairro
                       where b.idBairro == idBairro
                       select new
                       {
                           idBairro = b.idBairro,
                           idCidade = b.idCidade
                       });

    queryCidade = (from c in queryCidade
                   join b in queryBairro on c.idCidade equals b.idCidade
                   select new TesteConsulta
                   {
                       idCidade = c.idCidade
                   });
}
```

2° jeito:

```
IQueryable<TesteConsulta> queryCidade2 = (from c in db.ERPCEPCidade
                                          join b in db.ERPCEPBairro on c.idCidade equals b.idCidade
                                          select new TesteConsulta
                                          {
                                              idCidade = c.idCidade,
                                              idBairro = b.idBairro
                                          });

if (idBairro != 0)
{
    queryCidade2 = queryCidade2.Where(x => x.idBairro == idBairro);
}
```

No 1º jeito eu tenho a instância de 2 objetos Iqueryable, no 2º jeito eu tenho uma instância apenas, porém tenho mais dados na consulta, consequentemente no objeto de retorno e pior, é possível que o filtro seja vazio e eu nem utilize essa informação.

No banco de dados ficou dessa forma:

1° Jeito:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[idCidade] AS [idCidade]
FROM [dbo].[ERPCEPBairro] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[idCidade] IS NOT NULL) AND 
    ([Extent1].[idBairro] = 8626)
```

2° Jeito:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[idCidade] AS [idCidade], 
    [Extent1].[idBairro] AS [idBairro]
FROM [dbo].[ERPCEPBairro] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[idCidade] IS NOT NULL) AND 
    ([Extent1].[idBairro] = 8626)
```

Com essas informações, imagino que o 1° jeito seja o mais performático, mas como eu consigo me certificar? e quais outras boas práticas eu poderia aplicar na consulta?.

Lembrando que: isso é um exemplo, eu sei que nesse exemplo a diferença pode ser pequena, mas quando eu tenho consultas que trazem 40 mil registros, o custoé maior.

Comment: A questão é sobre Linq To Objects ou Linq To Entities?

Comment: Lendo o MDSN fiquei em dúvida, pois lá chamam de Linq to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas consultas não são equivalentes, mas a diferença entre elas é infima, a segunda está apenas a trazer uma coluna a mais (resultando em um trafego maior).

Porém ambas as consultas devem possuir o mesmo plano de execução, e exceto pela quantidade de dados trafegados, devem possuir o mesmo custo.

No mais o `EF` está a otimizar a sua consulta, pois o mesmo entendeu que o `LEFT JOIN` é desnecessário, podendo ser resumido a.:

```
from b in db.ERPCEPBairro
where b.idBairro == idBairro
select new TesteConsulta
{
    idCidade = b.idBairro
})
```

Comment: Consequentemente, o trafego maior numa consulta com 40k de registros, aumenta o tempo de execução, certo? Principalmente no caso de eu trazer a coluna de idBairro sem ter informado o filtro, ou seja, não preciso utilizá-lo.